# Failed to emit pre compiled header for a bridging header in Xcode 15 M1 Mac

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-m1, precompiled-headers, xcode15

I am using M1 Mac with Xcode 15, I am getting the below issue while executing 'Test'.

[image]

I have tried all the suggestions from google but none helped.
I have to build & run the code without 'Rosetta'.

Someone please help.

Comment: How are you adding `ESCObservable`? Note it hasn't been updated for 10 years.

Comment: it is not the problem with ESCObservable.. if I remove it, error shows to the next import file in Bridging-Header.

#import <ESCObservable/ESCObservable.h>